# Gradient of matrices formula with respect to one member?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, gradient-descent

For an machine learning assignement I have the following Loss-function:

$$L(D, W) = \frac{1}{2}||DW-X||^2_F$$
Where $D, W$ and $X$ are matrices.

In one part of the assignment I need to calculate the gradient of the Loss-function once with respect to $W$ and once with respect to $D$.

What I have so far, is that one can transform $||A||^2_F$ to $tr(A^TA) = tr(AA^T)$, which will give me
$$tr\Big((DW)(W^TD^T)-DWX^T-XW^TD^T+XX^T\Big)$$

I know that you get the gradient by deriving element-wise with respect to the elements of the respective matrix. However, I'm a bit stuck on solving this analytically. I think, the best way would be to further reduce the formula within the trace function above and then calculate the gradient element-wise, but I'm not really certain how to go about that.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: $$ \frac{\partial }{\partial W} \|W \|_{F}^{2} = \textrm{Tr}(WW^{H}) =  2W$$

Comment: @Shogun yeah, thanks, I also found [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277151/prove-that-gradient-of-operatornametra-cdot-b-cdot-at-cdot-c-with-r?rq=1) which I think could help. I will have a look at it and report back here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, with the help of Shogun's comment and the linked question I think I have found a solution. Maybe someone can confirm, that I didn't make any mistake (as this is rather unusable territory for me):

Assuming I made the result of the multiplication of the loss function with it's transpose is correct in this form
$$(DW)(W^TD^T)-DWX^T-XW^TD^T+XX^T$$
we want go on like this to solve with respect to $W$:
$$\nabla_Wtr\Big((DW)(W^TD^T)-DWX^T-XW^TD^T+XX^T\Big) = \\
\nabla_Wtr(DWW^TD^T) - \nabla_Wtr(DWX^T) - \nabla_Wtr(XW^TD^T) + \nabla_Wtr(XX^T)$$

Solving each part (using the methods shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277151/prove-that-gradient-of-operatornametra-cdot-b-cdot-at-cdot-c-with-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

$$\nabla_Wtr(DWW^TD^T) = 2D^TDW$$
$$\nabla_Wtr(DWX^T) = D^TX$$
$$\nabla_Wtr(XW^TD^T) = D^TX$$
$$\nabla_Wtr(XX^T) = 0$$

So altogether we get:
$$\nabla_Wtr\Big(L(D, W)\Big) = 2(D^TDW - D^TX)$$

The gradient with respect to $D$ be be solved in similar fashion.

Comment: somehow the shapes of the matrices don't fit (meanig I can't multiply them in the form of my solution), so there is definitely some mistake

Comment: Made a mistake transposing matrix multiplications, which should now be fixed. In my particular case the dimensions fit now.

Comment: looks good to me.